# How to fix: "Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)" error in java?

Tags: java, jdbc, sqlexception

I'm trying to learn JDBC Transactions I wrote some basic code to test it. However, while I'm running the code there are shown some errors in the output. Anyone could help me why is this happening and how to get rid of this?

This is the code:

```
public class JDBCTransactionExample {

    private static String db_url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
    private static String db_user = "root";
    private static String db_password = "root";

    private static final String INSERT_INTO_USER = "INSERT INTO user VALUES(?,?,?,?,?);";
    private static final String UPDATE_USER = "UPDATE user SET name = ? WHERE id = ?;";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db_url, db_user, db_password);
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);

            try {
                PreparedStatement insertStmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT_INTO_USER");
                PreparedStatement updateStmt = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE_USER");

                // Create insert statement
                insertStmt.setInt(1, 4);
                insertStmt.setString(2, "BBB");
                insertStmt.setString(3, "bbb@gmail.com");
                insertStmt.setString(4, "en");
                insertStmt.setString(5, "7894");
                insertStmt.executeUpdate();

                // Create update statement
                updateStmt.setString(1, "AAA");
                updateStmt.setInt(2, 4);
                updateStmt.executeUpdate();

                // STEP 2 - Commit insert and update statement
                conn.commit();
                System.out.println("Transaction is commited successfully.");

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                if (conn != null) {
                    try {
                        // STEP 3 - Roll back transaction
                        System.out.println("Transaction is being rolled back.");
                        conn.rollback();

                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).Transaction is being rolled back.
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.checkBounds(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1372)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.getCoreParameterIndex(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1385)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.setInt(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1573)
at jdbc.transaction.JDBCTransactionExample.main(JDBCTransactionExample.java:29)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant to use the constant instead of a `String` here:

```
PreparedStatement insertStmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT_INTO_USER");
PreparedStatement updateStmt = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE_USER");
```

should be

```
PreparedStatement insertStmt = conn.prepareStatement(INSERT_INTO_USER);
PreparedStatement updateStmt = conn.prepareStatement(UPDATE_USER);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final String INSERT_INTO_USER = "INSERT INTO user VALUES(?,?,?,?,?);";
private static final String UPDATE_USER = "UPDATE user SET name = ? WHERE id = ?;";
```

Glance at your string the symbol `;` is redundant, should be the following:

```
private static final String INSERT_INTO_USER = "INSERT INTO user VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
private static final String UPDATE_USER = "UPDATE user SET name = ? WHERE id = ?";
......
PreparedStatement insertStmt = conn.prepareStatement(INSERT_INTO_USER);
PreparedStatement updateStmt = conn.prepareStatement(UPDATE_USER);
```

Comment: Your code doesn't mention the actual fix (changing `"INSERT_INTO_USER"` and `"UPDATE_USER"` to `INSERT_INTO_USER` and `UPDATE_USER`). The removal of the `;` that you do mention explicitly might fix a subsequent problem, but is not the immediate problem of the question.

Comment: Yeah, removing the ; doesn't make any sense to the code but I think it is better to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

basically this error related to the ?  in the preparedStatement ( ?:  refer to the index of the parameters of the preparedStatement)

but with your case you already declared the sql query as String, so you don't need the double quotes, you just need to call the CONST UPDATE_USER and UPDATE_USER !

use:
PreparedStatement insertStmt = conn.prepareStatement(INSERT_INTO_USER);
PreparedStatement updateStmt = conn.prepareStatement(UPDATE_USER);